# exception when running jar, NoClassDefFoundError:org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, exception, jar

I have a spring project, it runs well in eclipse. But when i package it as a executable jar file and run it with command java -jar jar-name, it reports the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/c
ontext/ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.Applica
tionContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: cloud.ras.alert.RASAlertApp. Program will exit.
```

And even if i set the class-path value with springframework path, it still doesn't work.
And can anyone give me a help? Many thanks.

Comment: It is failing to load Springs jar files, are you sure that you have all your external libraries included in the build path?

Comment: do you mean that i should config the build path in manifest file?

Comment: Yes, you need to set the classpath while compiling, and also while running.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "springframework path"?

Comment: and i use maven, the dependency has existed in the pom.xml

Comment: to Gus, it represents the folder path of the spring framework jars.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> Export -> select Runnable Jar ->click Next in wizard -> Select "Copy Required Library into a sub folder next to the generated jar  and click Finish.

Since the jar is not able to find your relevant jar as runnable jar, you are facing this issue.

**IMP: Make sure you are using Eclipse JUNO.I am not sure with other versions of eclipse**

I was using Eclipse Ganymede and it does not has the option to select "Library Handling" option in the wizard page.

Comment: Works for Eclispe Mars! The goal is to select 'Runnable Jar File' and not the first option 'JAR file'.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't double check your classpath?
And you could try to add the jar path to you command as below:
java -cp .;jar_path_spring   -jar jar-name